# How to remove duplicate rows from specific column using macro vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a problem on how to remove rows with the same values for specific Columns in excel. 
*Please see screenshot below for my problem:*
[image]

In row **4:** **`FullName: A`**   **`SeqNo:003`** 
In row **5:** **`FullName: A`**   **`SeqNo:003`** 
So row **4** and **5** has the same value so I want to remove one of them but I don't want to remove row ***`automatically`*** by ***`random`*** but in condition that only the **`latest date will remain.`**

*Condition be like this:*
[image]

*This should be the correct output:*
[image]

So how can I achieve this by macro vba? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why I deserved a negative? This is already a detailed question. Please feel free comment if this question is not comprehensible.

Comment: (Not my vote) What have you researched / tried so far? Post your code.

Comment: Which version of MSOffice you are using

Comment: Do some transactions really not have a date?

Comment: I think your question is wrong. You don't want to just remove duplicate as per your table `highlighted` data is not duplicate if we consider each column in consideration. yep column specific data is look like duplicate. 
kindly update what actually you want

Comment: @Olly I've tried this code from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-removeduplicates-method-excel

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi I'm using MSoffice 2016

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald TransactionDate is always present per row.

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi Okay, I'll update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim X As New Collection
    Dim Str As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, c As Integer
    Dim n As Long

    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To r
        Str = vDB(i, 1) & vDB(i, 4)
        Err.Clear
        X.Add Str, Str
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To c, 1 To n)
            For j = 1 To c
                vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To r
            If vDB(j, 1) = vR(1, i) And vDB(j, 4) = vR(4, i) Then
                If vDB(j, 5) >= vR(5, i) Then
                    vR(2, i) = vDB(j, 2)
                    vR(5, i) = vDB(j, 5)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(n, c) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)

End Sub
```

Comment: @YouCrackedMeUp, you are wellcome.

Answer (score 1):

Record a macro of you sorting by the date column newest to oldest, then using the remove duplicates feature on the three columns but untick the date column in the remove duplicates dialogue. By default Excel keeps the first duplicate it comes to so by sorting you will remove the rows with older dates.

You should be able to tidy up the recorded code yourself.